# Java compiler throwing abstract method not over ridden despite over riding all abstract methods

Tags: java

So I am trying to extend an employee abstract class . The code is as follows :

```
abstract class Employee
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    
    Employee(String firstName,String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        String fullName = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        return fullName;
    }
    
    //abstract method 
    public abstract int getFeedback();
}

class SalesEmployee extends Employee
{
    double revenue;
    
    SalesEmployee(String firstName,String lastName,double revenue)
    {
        super(firstName,lastName);
        this.revenue = revenue;
    }
    
    public int getFeedback(double revenue)
    {
        if(revenue>55)
        {
            return 7;
        }
        else if (revenue>50)
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else if (revenue>40)
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if (revenue>30)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if (revenue>20)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
}

class CoderEmployee extends Employee
{
    int projects;
    
    CoderEmployee(String firstName,String lastName,int projects)
    {
        super(firstName,lastName);
        this.projects = projects;
    }
    
    public int getFeedback(int projects)
    {
        if(projects>20)
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if (projects>15)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else if (projects>10)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if (projects>5)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
}


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Now , as you can see I have over ridden the abstract method getFeedback in both the subclasses . Yet I am getting this error :

```
/tmp/eIRGYxws7Y/CoderEmployee.java:25: error: SalesEmployee is not abstract and does not override abstract method getFeedback() in Employee
class SalesEmployee extends Employee
^
/tmp/eIRGYxws7Y/CoderEmployee.java:66: error: CoderEmployee is not abstract and does not override abstract method getFeedback() in Employee
class CoderEmployee extends Employee
```

So what is the issue ? Why is this error being thrown despite writing getFeedback method in both the subclass

Comment: `getFeedback(double)` and `getFeedback(int)` are not implementations of `getFeedback()` (which specifies *no parameters*).

Comment: How ? I mentioned the function name and defined the function body ? What else am I supposed to do ?

Comment: Have the parameters match.

Comment: In Java, a method is determined by its signature. A signature is determined by its name and all parameters type. For example, `getFeedback()`'s signature is `getFeedback` while `getFeedback(double revenue)` is `getFeedback_double`. That's why `getFeedback(double revenue)` is not an overridden method of `getFeedback()`.

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Error messages are printed. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract `getFeedback()` method has no parameters, whereas your implementations have one. Therefore it is not overridden but rather overloaded. You'd have to add the parameter to the abstract definition as well. Also the types of the parameters in your implementations are inconsistent you'd have to have them match or be assignable to each other.

```java
// in Employee
public abstract int getFeedback(double revenue);

// In SalesEmployee
public int getFeedback(double revenue) {
    ...
}

// In CoderEmployee
public int getFeedback(double projects) {
    ...
}
```